# How do I prevent kids from launching minecraft and other games?

Tags: process-monitoring

There are students in my computer class who sit there and play minecraft all day. We're running OS X, and I'd like a find a way to kill the minecraft process as soon as its started to prevent students from playing it in class. What would be my options for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Crontab or CronniX (https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/7486/cronnix) to -kill it with a cron job every 60 seconds. Kids would probably never be able to figure it out.

Comment: Looking into it but I don't think it's what I need.

Comment: It wouldn't kill the game immediately, but it would almost be more frustrating because it would close out after a little bit. Almost like you'd be trolling them or something.

Comment: You could also look at parental controls under the Control Panel, but that might be a chore to deploy to all the machines. Never tried it in a group setting like that.